# Slider with continuous track which snaps to a specific value

Tags: flutter

I want to create the custom Slider from the deign below with a continuous track which would snap to a specific value which is shown below as a black rectangle.

I was able to recreate the custom Slider by setting defining custom `trackShape` and `thumbShape`.
I'm not sure how to snap the thumb when it's very close to the small black rectangle and how to make the black rectangle clickable.

The behavior is very similar to the Slider with discrete divisions but it should be continuous and the small black rectangle must be clickable.

[image: Slider design]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing it by myself with some inspiration from https://github.com/tomwyr/step-slider:

```
class SnapSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  SnapSlider({
    Key key,
    this.sliderKey,
    this.snapValues = const {},
    this.value,
    this.onSnapValueChanged,
    this.snapDistance = 0.05,
    this.animCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    this.animDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
    this.min: 0.0,
    this.max: 1.0,
    this.label,
    this.divisions,
    this.onChanged,
    this.onChangeEnd,
    this.onChangeStart,
    this.activeColor,
    this.inactiveColor,
    this.semanticFormatterCallback,
  })  : assert(snapValues != null),
        assert(snapValues.every((it) => it >= min && it <= max),
            'Each snap value needs to be within slider values range.'),
        super(key: key);

  final Key sliderKey;

  final Set<double> snapValues;

  final double value;

  final ValueChanged<double> onSnapValueChanged;

  final double snapDistance;

  final Curve animCurve;

  final Duration animDuration;

  final double min;

  final double max;

  final String label;

  final int divisions;

  final Color activeColor;

  final Color inactiveColor;

  final ValueChanged<double> onChanged;

  final ValueChanged<double> onChangeEnd;

  final ValueChanged<double> onChangeStart;

  final SemanticFormatterCallback semanticFormatterCallback;

  @override
  _StepSliderState createState() => _StepSliderState();
}

class _StepSliderState extends State<SnapSlider>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animator;
  CurvedAnimation _baseAnim;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  double _lastSnapValue;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(SnapSlider oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _animator.duration = widget.animDuration;
    _baseAnim.curve = widget.animCurve;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animator = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: widget.animDuration, value: 1.0);
    _baseAnim = CurvedAnimation(parent: _animator, curve: widget.animCurve);
    _recreateAnimation(widget.value, widget.value);
    _animation.addListener(() {
      _onSliderChanged(_animation.value);
      widget.onChanged?.call(_animation.value);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animator.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animator,
      builder: (_, __) => Slider(
        key: widget.sliderKey,
        min: widget.min,
        max: widget.max,
        label: widget.label,
        divisions: widget.divisions,
        activeColor: widget.activeColor,
        inactiveColor: widget.inactiveColor,
        semanticFormatterCallback: widget.semanticFormatterCallback,
        value: widget.value,
        onChangeStart: (it) {
          _animator.stop();
          _onSliderChangeStart(it);
          widget.onChangeStart?.call(it);
        },
        onChangeEnd: (it) {
          _onSliderChangeEnd(it);
          widget.onChangeEnd?.call(it);
        },
        onChanged: (it) {
          _onSliderChanged(it);
          widget.onChanged?.call(it);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onSliderChangeStart(double value) {
  }

  void _onSliderChangeEnd(double value) {
    double snapValue = _closestSnapValue(value);
    var distance = (value - snapValue).abs();
    if (snapValue != _lastSnapValue) {
      if (distance <= widget.snapDistance) {
        _animateTo(widget.value, snapValue, true);
        widget.onSnapValueChanged?.call(widget.value);
        _lastSnapValue = snapValue;
      }
    } else {
      if (distance > widget.snapDistance) {
        _lastSnapValue = null;
      }
    }
  }

  double _closestSnapValue(double value) {
    return widget.snapValues.reduce((a, b) {
      var distanceA = (value - a).abs();
      var distanceB = (value - b).abs();
      return distanceA < distanceB ? a : b;
    });
  }

  void _onSliderChanged(double value) {
  }

  void _animateTo(double start, double end, bool restart) {
    _recreateAnimation(start, end);
    _animator.forward(from: 0.0);
  }

  void _recreateAnimation(double start, double end) {
    _animation = Tween(begin: start ?? end, end: end).animate(_baseAnim);
  }
}
```